# 2.8 Add multiple image texture nodes simultaneously

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, image

I stopped using Blender for a while right when 2.8 rolled out. Trying to get back into it, I'm noticing that it seems to have removed the "import multiple image textures" option in the shader editor, which was useful for just batch dumping PBR textures (Diffuse, spec, rough, norm, disp, etc.) all at once. Now it seems I have to do it one at a time.

Am I missing something, or is there a node plugin I can get to streamline this? Something that just has all the image types you'd need built into one node? I've tried making a "PBR Texture" group node, but it's less than a perfect solution for multiple reasons.
[image]

As an additional aside, when I copy this node group and change the textures they link to, it also resets the color space to RGB from non-color data, which is rather annoying. Is there a way to stop that as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all enable Node wrangler addon

```
Edit > Preferences > Addons > Enable "Node Wrangler"
```

Now go to shading workspace and a principled shader
Select the shader and press CTRL + SHIFT + T and select all your files and click Principled texture setup.
Now blender will automatically set up all the nodes for you.

Comment: Thanks, I never really got the hang of Node Wrangler despite how useful it is. Chances are very high I'll forget that hotkey combo though. It'd be nice if there was just a a single node in the shift+a menu. It's actually pretty impressive that it reads the common image types from the file name and will auto-invert a gloss map for Blender. Edit* And now I see it also adds back "Multiple images." Thanks.

Comment: @JZStudios  You don't need to remember the shortcut, to add a principled setup, press 'N' on the keyboard to open the right hand panel and go to the "Node Wrangler" subpanel. There are multiple options there. If you have to remember only one shortcut, it would be SHIFt + W which opens this subpanel in a menu type format.